# How Can i pass url as a Vairable in Flask route

Tags: python-3.x, api, rest, flask

I want to pass a youtube link as a route parameter but it gives me an error

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def test():
 return 'Hello'

@app.route("/<path:url>") 

# a youtube link would be passed here

def get_data(url): 
 result = scrap(url) 
# do something with that url
 
return jsonify(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run(debug=True )
```

here i need a youtube link as a variable but the path:url does not give me full path so i cant use that link, is there a way so that i cant retrieve the full path?

Answer (score 0):

As it's a URL you're parsing, it might be better to parse it as a query parameter rather than a route parameter, this way it wouldn't be as easy for it to get mangled by the parser.

URL Query parameters can be extracted in flask using `request.args.get`

So your program would look something like this,

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def test():
 return 'Hello'

@app.route("/video") 
def get_video_data():
 url = request.args.get("url")
 result = scrape(url) 
 return jsonify(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run(debug=True)
```

Then you can pass the URL using http://localhost:8080/video?url=youtubeurl_here

Comment: Thanks for the help but I actually found a way around this, not so much professional, but it works...

Comment: I used the request method itself  i stored the full path of the url in variable and passed it
new_url  = request.full_path()